# How to decrypt PBEWithMD5AndDES String in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In my user table, the username column is encoded via PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm. Now I want something like this:

```
WITH TEMP
 AS (SELECT E.UAC_USER_ID AS ID,
            E.UAC_USER_USERNAME AS USERNAME,
            E.UAC_USER_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || E.UAC_USER_LASTNAME AS NAME,
            E.UAC_USER_PERSONELCODE AS PERSONELCODE
       FROM UAC_USERS E
      WHERE E.UAC_USER_ISENABLED = 1)
SELECT *
 FROM TEMP
WHERE 1 = 1 AND DECODE (USERNAME) = 'admin'
```

is there any embedded function in oracle that can decode the selected field?

Comment: Did you try to use Java in Oracle? Check [Calling Java in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I can only give you direction to solve problem, not answer.

Oracle has package dbms_crypto which **may be** can help you.

See examples https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65690
You can find encryption_type

```
 encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC -- description in doc
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5; -- description in doc
```

In DBMS_CRYPTO there is another constant DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_PBE_MD5DES.
Theoretically this may help:

```
 encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                                DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_PBE_MD5DES
                              + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC -- description in doc
                              + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5; -- description in doc
```

But using this encryption_type in code I get error. I also try several combination and change code but finally i give up. May be one of the reason is the constant DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_PBE_MD5DES doesn't described in doc or I should change smt else in example. .